# Typescript allows building invalid partial object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was trying to build a partial helper function in Typescript, and while trying, I built an incorrect version of it, that Typescript didn't catch:

Typescript version: 5.2.2

```
type A = { a: number; b: string };

// bad
const buildPartialBad = (key: keyof A, val: A[keyof A]): Partial<A> => ({ [key]: val });
const test1 = buildPartialBad('a', 'hello'); // allows me to build an invalid object

// good
const buildPartialGood = <K extends keyof A>(key: K, val: A[K]): Partial<A> => ({ [key]: val });
const test2 = buildPartialGood('a', 'hello'); // compile error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

I can't understand why the buildPartialBad function does not show any error.

I found Partial-related issues on StackOverflow and GitHub but they weren't exactly this case, and the issue seemed to be a bit too silly for it to be a TS bug. Maybe I am not completely awake :)

Any explanation would be welcome :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `buildPartialBad`, there's no relationship between the first parameter type and the second parameter type, so the `"a"` as the first parameter value is valid (it's a `keyof A`), and the `"hello"` as the second parameter value is valid (it's a `number | string`, since that's what `A[keyof A]` is). Separately, I think the reason the return value doesn't raise any flags is that the types are too open (`key` is `keyof A` [`"a" | "b"`], and `val` is `A[keyof A]` [`number | string`]), so TypeScript can't flag the object as being incorrect.

In your second version, you've added a relationship between the parameters, so by specifying `"a"` as the first parameter value, you've told TypeScript that `val` *has* to be `A["a"]`, which is `number`. So it won't let you pass a string.

Comment: thanks for the answer :)

I understand the difference, but I'm still unsure why Typescript wouldn't catch it.
It seems like a relatively simple case, and the implementation of Partial seems to be doing a good job at relating the key to the value type
```
/**
 * Make all properties in T optional
 */
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};

```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `Partial`, you could have returned `void` and the result would have been the same (actually I think you should return `{ [k in K]: A[K] }`). `Partial<A>` is just transforming `A` independently of the checks you do on the inputs in both of your implementations. There is nothing that TS did wrong in your first implementation, you told it to accept any value of `A`, and `string` is a value of `A`, it is only by inferring the generic `K` which you relate with the input `key` that you become able to express something like "the value corresponding to that key" (`A[K]`)

Comment: mmh, interesting.

the question becomes why can I define Partial on strings, or keyof on something that is not an object

Comment: @f-g-p I don't see how the two questions are connected, but using `keyof` on a string type will simply give you the keys on the `String` prototype since any primitive string can be implicitly wrapped in a `String`. Trying to make sense of TS on degenerate cases is not going to help build your intuition though, because many things are simply special cased.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put it is that in `buildPartialGood` you are inferring `K` as the string literal `"a"`, so `A[K]` is substituted with `A["a"]`, which is `number`.